# docker-compose : 2 applications using the same mysql-instance

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 different project, each with their own docker-compose.yml-file.

**(1) The first** project has a tomcat-container with App-1 + a mysql-container

**(2) The second** project has a tomcat-container with App-2.

In this project I want to use the same database as in the first project.

At first I will deploy the both projects on the same machine, in the next phase I would like to move the second-project to another machine.

regards,i

Comment: Could you be a little more clear, what is the question here?

Comment: @hichamx : I have a project that is running on tomcat and using a mysql-database. These 2 services are configured in the same in the same docker-compose.yml-file (version 3.1). Now I would like to break out the database into a separate project ( its own docker-compose.yml) and then move that project to a new host. I managed to break out the database and link to the database from tomcat using external_links:
    - db:db (now I need to figure out how to connect to the database when the project has moved to another host - different IP)

Comment: The database and the App both should be in the same network, if it's not the case, I guess you have to do some port mapping, did you publish MySQL port?

Comment: Have not done that yet,I guess that could be a solution .... if I am running my tomcat on ip 172.168.10.12 and my mysql on ip 172.168.10.14 under the name 'db' - so the question is how I can reach the db-service from 172.168.10.12? should I use the IP instead of 'db' something like db:db:13306 ? if 13306 is my port ?

Comment: In Mysql docker-compose file add
`    ports:
     - "13306:3306 "
`
then from 172.168.10.12 you can reach the database using 172.168.10.14:13306

Answer (score 0):

@hichamx :

(1) This is my original setting with the db is running on the same host.
(ip=172.168.10.12)

```
tomcat:
  image: myimage:v3.1
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.local
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
  external_links:
   - db:db
```

(2) now I want to start the db on the second host (ip=172.168.10.14) and I have mapped the port to 3306:3306.

```
tomcat:
      image: myimage:v3.1
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.local
        - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
      external_links: 
        - db:db
        #- lenovo:db # 'service:alias'
      extra_hosts:
        - "lenovo:172.168.10.14"
        - "db:172.168.10.14"
```

I am running the database now on port 3306 on the 172.68.10.14-machine ( mapped to lenovo and db in 'extra-hosts' .... I only seem to be able to map db:db in my external links ... ) This setup does work and I never have to touch the context.xml-file below. ( would like to sort out the mapping and be able to use 'lenovo' or some other name ...)

my tomcat-application is mapped to 'db' in the context.xml-file :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DBWeb" 
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                maxActive="100"
                maxIdle="30"
                maxWait="10000"
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                testOnBorrow="true"
                username="user" 
                password="secret" 
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://db/personal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"/>
```

where 'personal', in the above url-string,  would be my database and 'db' is the alias for the database (mapped in the docker-compose.yml-file)

Thank you for the help @hichamx for setting me straight.

Comment: You are welcome, as for external_links, I guess it has to be something like `CONTAINER_NAME:ALIAS` in your case `DB_CONTAINER_NAME:db`